# PHP: basic percentage calculation

Tags: php, math

I have `$sum` and need to calculate the sum minus 15% and then I need to display the original value again.

```
$sum = 199;
echo "value 1: $sum";
$sum = $sum*0.85;
echo "value 2: $sum";
$foo = $sum*1.15; 
echo "value 3: $foo";
```

This is the result I get:

```
value 1: 199 
value 2: 169.15 
value 3: 194.5225
```

Please tell a very stupid person why this formula is obviously wrong and doesn't return 199 in the last output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Percentages don't work that way. You can't just do the reverse to the result of the first operation. You should just store the original number and use that.

Comment: Went with your advice. Today, I learned that even math can fail because it doesn't have built-in memory.

Comment: Spiny Norman's answer says how to get back the original number (by division - which is inverse of multiplication). So, it is not necessary to store the original number.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with everybody about just keeping the original variable. However, the single-variable answer is this:

```
1.99 * .85 = 169.15
169.15 / .85 = 1.99
```

Change operator ;)

Comment: `1.99 * .85 = 1.6915`

Answer (score 1):

It's because 1/1.15 is not equal to 0.85.

Comment: So how do I fix that? Please, I graduated from the George w Bush school of mathematonics, I ain't smart!

Comment: :) Well, if you want to reverse the operation, you should divide by the number you multiplied by. So, in this case you would do `$foo = $sum / .85`. However, as @ryeguy said, if you need the original value, you might as well print the original value...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you starting off with `199` and finding 85% of that (the subtract 15%) which is correct. But now, when you're trying to gain the 15% back you're doing so based on the value of `15% of 169.15` (25.3725) not `15% of 199` (29.85).

As mentioned in another answer, if you need to original number back, keep it in a variable and use a temp variable to hold the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum = 199;
echo "value 1: $sum<br />";
$sum2 = $sum*0.85;
echo "value 2: $sum2<br />";
echo "value 3: $sum<br />";
```

So, who's the genius?